# 1 part of the sidebar at top, rest at bottom

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, rwd, sidebar

Okay, so I have a sidebar in one of my CMS pages. This sidebar has 3 static blocks:

- a menu (accordeon on mobile devices)
- a contact block
- an USP block

The HTML is roughly set up like this:

```
<div class="content">

   <p>Some content</p>

</div>

<div class="sidebar">

  <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
    <h5>Menu</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
    <h5>Contact us</h5>
    <p>Some text related to contacting the vendor</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
    <ul class="usp">
      <li>USP</li>
      <li>USP</li>
      <li>USP</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

The sidebar is on the right of the page. When I switch to a mobile device (770px media query), I want ONLY the menu block to be at the top of the page. The rest of the sidebar has to display at the bottom of the page. How do I do this, without changing HTML, and not using bad practice?

Structure how I want it on mobile devices:

- Menu block
- Content
- Contact block
- USP block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An container added wrapped to all block**

```
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.container .sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 100%
    padding: 0 20px;
}
@media (max-width:700px) {
    .container {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .container .content {
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .container .sidebar {
        order: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">

        <p>Some content</p>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">

        <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
            <h5>Menu</h5>
            <ul>
                <li>menu item</li>
                <li>menu item</li>
                <li>menu item</li>
                <li>menu item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
            <h5>Contact us</h5>
            <p>Some text related to contacting the vendor</p>
        </div>

        <div class="block"><!-- static block -->
            <ul class="usp">
                <li>USP</li>
                <li>USP</li>
                <li>USP</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthikannan/zwzyfdv0/

Comment: This places the sidebar above the content, and that is not what I'm asking :p

Comment: You can re-arrange the block as per your need with the help of Order:1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

**For your old question**

```css
 .container {
  max-width:700px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
```

}
  .container .content {
      width:calc(100% - 280px);
      float:left;
      padding:0 20px;
  }
  .container .sidebar {
      float:right;
      width:200px;
      padding:0 20px;
  }

@media (max-width: 700px) {

```
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .content {
 order: 2;
 width: 100%;
```

}
 .container .sidebar {
     order: 1;
     width: 100%;
 }
}

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
        Some content and a good story about the website.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
   <h3>
     Sidebar navigation
 </h3>
 <ul>
     <li>Menu item</li>
     <li>Menu item</li>
     <li>Menu item</li>
     <li>Menu item</li>
     <li>Menu item</li>
 </ul>
```